# DISPLAY and GNOME_SETUP_DISPLAY

Tags: environment-variables, wayland

I am on Ubuntu 22.04.2, under wayland (xwayland)

I echoed DISPLAY and GNOME_SETUP_DISPLAY, but the values differs.

$DISPLAY=:0
$GNOME_SETUPDISPLAY=:2

I would like to know why mismatches

Why?

And what about MUTTER_DISPLAY?

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show us the values of `$DISPLAY` and `$GNOME_SETUP_DISPLAY`, and explain why you think different environment variables should have the same value.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].

Comment: They're different variables, containing different values, used by different programs, for different purposes. Again, why do you think they should be the same? To see the environment variables used  by a `program`, do `strings $(type -p program) | grep -E '^[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]+$' | sort -u | more`.

Comment: Sorry, i was thinking as xorg user, playing with wayland (xwayland) ...
Complete different story i think